# Connection Refused when trying to acess Ubuntu 12.04 using putty from windows,ssh installed

Tags: putty

Connection Refused when trying to access Ubuntu 12.04 using putty from windows,ssh installed below is the ufw status from ubuntu system

```
root@anant-Compaq-Presario-CQ40-Notebook-PC:/home/anant# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
7001                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       192.168.2.0/24
8001                       ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
Samba                      ALLOW       Anywhere
7001                       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8001                       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Samba (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Please help me anyone, even i cannot access from the windows machine , the  weblogic console which runs on 7001 port of ubuntu

Comment: Take a look in `/etc/hosts.deny` and `/etc/hosts.allow`

Comment: Do you try to connect from 192.168.2.0/24 ?
Also, do you use ssh key to connect ?